# The connection between ركن and corner

Tags: english, etymology, historical-linguistics, arabic

The arabic word ركن  /rukn/  and the English word corner /ˈkɔɹnɚ/.

Is there any connections between them?

Comment: What makes *you* think they are connected? We prefer well-researched questions as they are more answerable. This is especially true in case of etymology questions. Please check [this](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1962/1009) and [this](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1838/1009) for further details.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question lacks basic research.

Comment: My question based on the similar connection between دار and door. They're connected

Comment: Have you looked up either etymology?

Answer (score 4):

The only connection is that they mean the same thing. Spanich *rincón* which also means "corner" is borrowed from Arabic *rukn*. The English word comes from Latin via French and originally meant "horn".

Comment: There's one more connection, a phonetic one – both words contain [r], [k], [n] and a rounded vowel.

Comment: @YellowSky it's pretty tenuous though, the k & r are the wrong way round, English has an extra syllable (with an extra r on it), and the rounded vowel is different. If these were two languages known to be part of the same family it might be worth investigating if they're cognates, but without any such prior knowledge it doesn't seem close to enough to justify consideration

Comment: @Tristan - Yes, you're right, but that's perhaps the connection the OP meant when asking the question.